# How do I fix this shower drain?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, leak, pvc

A couple days ago I noticed in the ceiling some dripping water after taking a shower. There was really no reason the pipe would have broken, so I pulled up the shower grate thinking it was maybe somewhere between the connection to the drain pipe. My theory was there probably was just a worn out gasket somewhere along the way.

I didn't install this shower, I'm guessing this outer white piece ring seals with the lower PVC piece, and that is what creates the connection. A gasket must be underneath it which then seals the floor of the shower.

Is that correct? I also couldn't tell if that black ring stuff was some sort of sealant breaking off.. Does anyone recognize this? How would I go about fixing something like this? threading it off and putting a new gasket underneath? I just need to be careful as I have no access behind without ripping up drywall.

pictures for reference:

[image]

a second more zoomed out angle (slightly blurry, sorry!)

[image]

Comment: My first suspicion would be water seeping in behind the faucet handles, behind the bath spout if there is one, the caulking where the tub or shower tray meets the wall, bad grout lines, or the seal around any other built-in fixture e.g. soap dish.  Drains don't fail as often as caulk lines, and when they do, you get pouring not dripping.

Comment: The flange unscrews and the seal is normally there.it may be breaking down and causing the leak. I have had only limited success with plastic drains but the ones that would unscrew without tearing things up a new seal or plumbers putty was all it took to fix, the flat rubber seals are two thick for plumbers putty but if the seal is not old rubber it is probably plumbers putty. I found spraying the pvc threads both sides with spray silicone really helped to thread the plastic back together and I was able to tighten without cracking.

Comment: Water does funny things and there are many places it could be coming from in a shower.  I wouldn't just assume it's the drain. As @jay613 mentioned it is more likely a caulking issue. If you're going to replace the ceiling drywall where it leaked you might want to open that up first. It'll give you a much better idea of what's going on and if the problem is with the drain. Once it's open, run the shower and you'll know pretty quick.

Comment: If you do end up having to cut drywall, I recommend installing a frame and an "access plate" for the next time someone needs to access the plumbing.